# Concat two dataframe with different timedeltas

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, concatenation

Hello I am trying to concat two dataframes based on this logic :
I have a first df `df_minutes` that contains data for each minute and a second `df_hourly` that contains data with an hour delay.

I need to add the column RSI-1H of my 2nd dataframe to the first and get the same value 56 for all the rows from 00:00 to 00:59; 58 for all the rows from 01:00 to 01:59, etc ...

**df_minutes**

```
                      index           unix    symbol    open    high     low  
date                                                                                                                  
2022-01-01 00:00:00  525599  1640995200000  AVAXUSDT  109.43  109.88  109.42  
2022-01-01 00:01:00  525598  1640995260000  AVAXUSDT  109.75  110.09  109.58  
2022-01-01 00:02:00  525597  1640995320000  AVAXUSDT  109.98  110.16  109.87  
2022-01-01 00:03:00  525596  1640995380000  AVAXUSDT  110.06  110.11  109.74  
2022-01-01 00:04:00  525595  1640995440000  AVAXUSDT  109.76  110.06  109.72  
 ...
2022-01-01 01:08:00  525591  1640995680000  AVAXUSDT  110.24  110.30  110.17  
2022-01-01 01:09:00  525590  1640995740000  AVAXUSDT  110.18  110.29  110.02 
 ....
2022-01-01 02:18:00  525591  1640995680000  AVAXUSDT  110.24  110.30  110.17  
2022-01-01 02:19:00  525590  1640995740000  AVAXUSDT  110.18  110.29  110.02
```

**df_hourly**

```
                     RSI-1H           
date                                                                                                                  
2022-01-01 00:00:00  56    
2022-01-01 01:00:00  58  
2022-01-01 02:00:00  59    
2022-01-01 03:00:00  60    
2022-01-01 04:00:00  59
```

I need to obtain this result :

**final_df**

```
                      index           unix    symbol    open    high     low    RSI-1H
date                                                                                                                  
2022-01-01 00:00:00  525599  1640995200000  AVAXUSDT  109.43  109.88  109.42   56
2022-01-01 00:01:00  525598  1640995260000  AVAXUSDT  109.75  110.09  109.58   56
2022-01-01 00:02:00  525597  1640995320000  AVAXUSDT  109.98  110.16  109.87   56
2022-01-01 00:03:00  525596  1640995380000  AVAXUSDT  110.06  110.11  109.74   56
2022-01-01 00:04:00  525595  1640995440000  AVAXUSDT  109.76  110.06  109.72   56
 ...
2022-01-01 01:08:00  525591  1640995680000  AVAXUSDT  110.24  110.30  110.17   58
2022-01-01 01:09:00  525590  1640995740000  AVAXUSDT  110.18  110.29  110.02   58
 ....
2022-01-01 02:18:00  525591  1640995680000  AVAXUSDT  110.24  110.30  110.17   59
2022-01-01 02:19:00  525590  1640995740000  AVAXUSDT  110.18  110.29  110.02.  59
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

this is done using pandas resample

for upsampling (your case) you can choose from forward fillig (your case) or other filling methods

```
df_minute["new"] = df_hourly.resample('60S').ffill()
```

on mobile and not tested

link to [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can pick just the column that you need, if both df have the same number of lines.

```
import pandas as pd
id = ['0','1','2']
date = ['10-10','10-11','10-12']
local = ['a','b','c']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': id, 'Date': date, 'local': local})

comp = ['big', 'small', 'big']

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Id': id, 'Complement': comp})

df['Complement'] = df_2['Complement']

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is am easy way to go. The magic happens in one line

```
import pandas as pd

# data for 120 minutes
df_minutes = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, 120),
    columns=["minute_data"],
    index=pd.date_range(
        "2022-01-01 00:00:00",
        "2022-01-01 01:59:00",
        freq="60S",
    )
)

# data for two hours
df_hourly = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, 2),
    columns=["hour_data"],
    index=pd.date_range(
        "2022-01-01 00:00:00",
        "2022-01-01 01:59:00",
        freq="60Min",
    )
)

# save for later
old_index = df_minutes.index

# truncate minute index to join on hours
df_minutes.index = df_minutes.index.floor("1H")

# perform magic
df_minutes = df_minutes.join(df_hourly)

# restore old index
df_minutes.index = old_index

# result
df_minutes
```